# Getting a pointer to `uint` in Solidity

Tags: solidity, evm

I have a `uint pos;`

I want to get a pointer to `pos`.

In C, I would do something like:

```
uint posptr = &pos;
```

How to do something similar in Solidity? It's fine if it's in assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a simple declaration inside a function such as :

```
uint posptr;
```

This won't be possible, as per my understanding, those variables only live on the stack and don't have a definitive usable memory address (Stack and Memory are separated in the EVM as you can see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/interpreter.go#L41) for go-ethereum)

However, I suppose that you could wrap your variable into a struct that you declare in memory and therefore have a pointer like behavior as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour) :

> Assignments from memory to memory only create references. This means
> that changes to one memory variable are also visible in all other
> memory variables that refer to the same data.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {

    struct uInt256Ptr {
        uint256 value;
    }

    function pointer() public pure returns (uint256, uint256) {
        uInt256Ptr memory a;
        uInt256Ptr memory b = a; // b is a pointer to a

        b.value = 1;

        return (a.value, b.value);
        // returns ("1", "1")
    }
}
```

Maybe someone has a better idea, but I would discourage such practice in your code. There must be a more solidity friendly (and readable) way to achieve your goal.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you!! I like this approach. I also had an idea yesterday to use a 1-element array of uints and use that array as a pointer and then array[0] as a way to dereference that pointer. I should measure which way saves more gas. Cheers.